# SVM: giving probabilities by sigmoid

Tags: svm

For example, as for a binary classification problem, SVM usually gives a classifier rather than Probs.

In other words, the SVM may gives us hyper-parameter, e.g., $W = [w0, w1, w2]$ for our data $X_{train} = [1, x1, x2]$, and we can use $W$ to get a "delimiting line" to do classification.

**Now the question is:** 
Ever since we used hinge-cost to train a SVM, we already had $W$. Could we use sigmoid to give probabilities of prediction = 1/0 , such as $sigmoid(W \times X_{validation})$ or $sigmoid(W \times X_{train})$ ?

Comment: This is called Platt Scaling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling The more interesting question might be what its properties are, and how to avoid the [tag:Hauck-Donner-effect].

Comment: Thanks for answer, Genral Abrial ! A detail:  the $f(x)$ in the wiki page may correspond to something in the SVM classifier. May I assume $f(x)$ corresponds to the distance from the data point to the SVM classifier line ? (The more the abs of  the distance is, the more confident we get a good classification)

Comment: I think that the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article under "Description" will make that notation clear to you.